# Using 'scrat' name in a web app

Tags: websites, copyright

Is there any problem that I may have in the future if I use the name 'scrat' in an web app for App Store? For example 'Scrat Store' or something similar?

Since the name 'scrat' is the name of an Ice Age character and obviously is trademarked.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Apple Hardware/Software as outlined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a trademarked name then you will have a problem.  It might get through the app review process the first and second time but eventually, the trademark owner, in this case, **20th Century Fox**, will find out and and ask/tell you to remove it (or go to Apple to have it removed).